# Picking rows from two NumPy arrays at random

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, random

Starting from two numpy arrays:

```py
A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
B = np.array([[9, 8], [8, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5]])
```

I would like to create a new array `C` picking, for each index, one row from the same index but randomly from `A` or `B`. The idea is that at each index of `random_selector`, if the value is higher than `0.1`, then we chose the same-index row from `A`, otherwise, the same-index row from `B`.

```py
random_selector = np.random.random(size=len(A))

C = np.where(random_selector > .1, A, B)

# example of desired result picking rows from respectively A, B, B, A:
# [[1, 2], [8, 7], [7, 6], [4, 5]]
```

Running the above code, however, produces the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,2) (4,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a new dimension:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
B = np.array([[9, 8], [8, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5]])

random_selector = np.random.random(size=len(A))

C = np.where((random_selector > .1)[:, None], A, B)
print(C)
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
[[1 2]
 [8 7]
 [3 4]
 [4 5]]
```

Comment: Interesting that it works. It sounds intuitive enough in retrospect, but I wouldn't have thought of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of stuff in Numpy is like that.